# as troubling as rewarding?

Tags: grammaticality, comparative-constructions, as

It is a question about "as adjective as adjective" construction.

I wrote a sentence:

> The book was as sad as happy.

My friend, looking at the sentence, said that it should be

> The book was as sad as it was happy.

I was like, OK, then what about this?

> The book was sad as much as happy.

He said it's OK.

I don't see the logic behind it. Is there a grammar rule about it?

Answer (score 2):

We say

> The box was as tall as it was wide.

but not this:

> The box was as tall as wide.

I suppose that is because we are comparing one predicate with another predicate, not merely adjective with adjective.

The box was as tall
as the box was wide

> That piano piece is as tranquil as it is stormy.

We are  comparing one *degree* with another.

*it is tranquil* to the same degree that *it is stormy*.

Comment: Thank you. _The book was sad as much as happy._  In this case, the predicate can be used just by itself after the second "as", without the subject and linking verb. I wonder why that is possible when used with "much"?

Comment: Because "as *much* as" turns the comparison to a comparison of the degree of the properties as they are possessed by the book; is not just comparing adjective to adjective.

Comment: Does it mean that I can say "the piano piece is as tranquil as stormy" without having to say "the piano piece is as tranquil as it is stormy"?

Comment: What is "it" in "Does it..." ?

Comment: Your comment above, but I guess it sounds strange. Sorry.

Comment: My comment above refers to the word "much".  You could say "The piano piece was tranquil as much as stormy".

Comment: Yes, but you mentioned in the answer that "tranquil" and "stormy" are compared as degree, so I just thought "maybe..."

Comment: Well, **tall** and **wide** are also a comparison of *degree*, as measured in some unit of length.   We just don't have tranquility units. Though I suppose we do have storm categories that express storm intensity. :)

Comment: Degree or extent.

Comment: Ok. So I guess the reason "it is as good as dead" is grammatical is because it is a set idiom or something?  Am I right?

Comment: That does not translate to "it was as good as it was dead", paralleling tranquil/stormy. Rather, **good** performs a similar role to that played by **much** , referring to the *extent* to which it is dead.  It's got so little life left, we could say it was dead.

Comment: **Good** can refer to the size or *extent* of something.  "Give it a *good* shove".  A **goodly** flock is an *extensive* flock.

Comment: Ah.... it feels quite abstract. How can one distinguish between extent and degree when an adjective is used?

Comment: You don't need to distinguish between extent and degree.  You just need to say "it was as tranquil as it was stormy" and have done with it.   But you pressed for an *explanation*, wanting to know *why* we can say "sad as much as happy" and  "as good as dead" but not "as tranquil as sad". It was the explanation that became abstract. Stick to "as x as it was y" and you can't go wrong.  Unless you're trying to say "as good as dead", which, as I said, is not a comparison between two predicates but tantamount to saying "it was practically dead, beyond moribund".

Comment: Thank you! I finally got the hang of it. Not the comparison of two predicates, that is what I needed to understand. I really appreciate your explanation.

Comment: Compare: "He *as much as* said that".  He practically came out and said it; for all intents and purposes what he did say came very close to saying that.  **as much as** could be paraphrased "practically" or "nearly".  The variant is "He as good as said that".

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is correct.

> His eye was as black as blue.

Although this is grammatically correct, it isn't semantically correct.  To say that something is as black as blue means that you consider blue to be .. well, black, which it is not.

It makes more sense to say

> His eye was as black as night.

Now we have a strong comparison.  Though, if you really want to incorporate `blue` into the sentence, you'll have to recreate the usage of the adjective.

> His eye was as black as it was blue.

In this instance, each side of the comparison utilizes the verb `to be` in the past tense.  And, we can infer from that usage that his eye was both black and blue.

In your case, you're describing a relationship as *being* both troubling and rewarding, so you must define it as such on each side of your comparison.

> It is as troubling as it is rewarding

It may help to think of using the word, *while*, which allows two phrases to be simultaneous in nature.

> It is troubling while it is rewarding.

---

To expand on your own example,

> The relationship was troubling as much as rewarding

We can say this because the word troubling does not follow an `as`, it isn't part of the comparison.  On it's own, we can omit the comparison and it makes sense.

> The relationship was troubling

But, if you decide to make `troubling` part of the comparison, then you'll put `like` or `as` in front of it.  Realize how the following sentence lacks something.

> The relationship was as troubling.

Now, we have an incomplete sentence.

Comment: Thank you. But then why can we say: The relationship was troubling as much as rewarding? It is like saying: His eye was black as much as blue.And there is not much difference between "His eye was as black as blue" and "his eye was black as much as blue". Both of them uses "as adjective as adjective" construction.

Comment: We can say that because, there is no `as` in front of `troubling`.

Comment: `it is as good as dead` vs `it is good as much as dead`

Comment: Hm. What is the difference? Wait. It is as adjective as adjective...

Comment: Right.  If you're going to compare two things they must be interchangeable.  You can't compare `It is green` with `orange`.  You have to actually say, `It is orange`.

Comment: You mean I can use "as adjective as adjective" construction if two adjectives are interchangeable? But how is good and dead interchangeable?

Comment: They are both adjectives.

Comment: Troubling and rewarding are both adjectives.

Comment: Perhaps interchangeable wasn't the right word to use.  Because I did use the example `as black as night`.  Which can also be understood as `black like night`

Comment: I edited my question for better understanding. What do you think of edited sentences?

Comment: I edited my answer for better understanding. :)